# How can I type this function that accepts a mixin function as argument?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a function called `Mixin` that accepts a single argument. The argument should be a "class factory mixin".

For example, suppose I have this class factory mixin function:

```
type Constructor<T = any, A extends any[] = any[]> = new (...a: A) => T

const CoolMixin = <T extends Constructor>(Base: T) => {
  return class CoolMixin extends Base {
    coolProp = 42
  }
}

const CoolFoo = CoolMixin(class Foo {
    foo = 'asdf'
})

const c = new CoolFoo()

// it works:
c.foo
c.coolProp
```

([playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Constructor%3CT%20%3D%20any%2C%20A%20extends%20any%5B%5D%20%3D%20any%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20new%20(...a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20T%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20CoolMixin%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20Constructor%3E(Base%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20class%20CoolMixin%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20coolProp%20%3D%2042%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20CoolFoo%20%3D%20CoolMixin(class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%20%3D%20'asdf'%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20c%20%3D%20new%20CoolFoo()%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20it%20works%3A%0D%0Ac.foo%0D%0Ac.coolProp%0D%0A))

As you see it accepts a base class and returns a new class, and it works fine.

I have a `Mixin` utility that takes a mixin function, and gives it cool features like `hasInstance` support, caching against duplicate applications of base classes, and other features.

In plain JavaScript, I can use it like this:

```js
// Mixin returns an application of the Mixin function (a class) with
// a default base class applied (Object by default):
const CoolMixin = Mixin((Base) => {
  return class CoolMixin extends Base {
    coolProp = 42
  }
})


// Here, CoolMixin is `class CoolMixin extends Object {...}`,
// so we can use it like a regular class:
let CoolFoo = class Foo extends CoolMixin {
    foo = 'asdf'
}


// Mixin returns that class with a static `.mixin` property containing
// the original mixin function, so we can also use it as a mixin:
CoolFoo = CoolMixin.mixin(class Foo {
    foo = 'asdf'
})

// either of the two versions will work the same:
const c = new CoolFoo()
c.foo
c.coolProp
```

So the convenience of my utility (aside from features like caching, hasInstance, etc) is that it can be used however is most convenient. Here are two more example:

```js
// suppose One and Two are mixins created with my Mixin utility.

// Use regular extension:
class Foo extends One {...}
class Bar extends Two {...}

// or compose them together:
class Baz extends One.mixin(Two) {...}
```

So, I'd like to figure how to make typing for this `Mixin` utility in TypeScript.

My first attempt is the following, which doesn't work, but I think it shows the idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
type Constructor<T = any, A extends any[] = any[]> = new (...a: A) => T

type MixinFunction = <TSub, TSuper>(base: Constructor<TSuper>) =>
  Constructor<TSub & TSuper>

declare function Mixin<TSub, TSuper, T extends MixinFunction>(mixinFn: T):
  Constructor<TSub & TSuper> & {mixin: T}

// Then using it like so:

const CoolMixinFunction = <T extends Constructor>(Base: T) => {
  return class CoolMixin extends Base {
    coolProp = 42
  }
}

const CoolMixin = Mixin(CoolMixinFunction)

const CoolFoo = CoolMixin.mixin(class Foo {
    foo = 'asdf'
}

const c = new CoolFoo()
c.foo
c.coolProp

const CoolBar = class Bar extends CoolMixin {
    bar = 'asdf'
})

const b = new CoolBar()
b.bar
b.coolProp
```

([playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Constructor%3CT%20%3D%20any%2C%20A%20extends%20any%5B%5D%20%3D%20any%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20new%20(...a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20T%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20MixinFunction%20%3D%20%3CTSub%2C%20TSuper%3E(base%3A%20Constructor%3CTSuper%3E)%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20Constructor%3CTSub%20%26%20TSuper%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20Mixin%3CTSub%2C%20TSuper%2C%20T%20extends%20MixinFunction%3E(mixinFn%3A%20T)%3A%0D%0A%20%20Constructor%3CTSub%20%26%20TSuper%3E%20%26%20%7Bmixin%3A%20T%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Then%20using%20it%20like%20so%3A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20CoolMixinFunction%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20Constructor%3E(Base%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20class%20CoolMixin%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20coolProp%20%3D%2042%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20CoolMixin%20%3D%20Mixin(CoolMixinFunction)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20CoolFoo%20%3D%20CoolMixin.mixin(class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%20%3D%20'asdf'%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20c%20%3D%20new%20CoolFoo()%0D%0Ac.foo%0D%0Ac.coolProp%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20CoolBar%20%3D%20class%20Bar%20extends%20CoolMixin%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%20%3D%20'asdf'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20new%20CoolBar()%0D%0Ab.bar%0D%0Ab.coolProp%0D%0A))

As you may infer, I'm trying to type the `Mixin` tool so that it accepts a mixin function, and the return type of the `Mixin` call should be a class which is generated from the mixin function, and that returned class should also have a `.mixin` property which is the same type as the passed-in mixin function.

I know that I'm doing it wrong. I'm not clear on how I can use type inference here.

It seems like the new ["Higher order function type inference"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) feature might be useful here.

How may I achieve this `Mixin` utility typing? Can I do it without that higher order feature? And how to do it with that feature?

Comment: My *guess* is that the higher-order support will get better in TS3.5 which will incorporate [this pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31116), since you are specifically looking at constructor types here.  But this is just a guess for now.

Answer (score 1):

This makes the code compile and all the prop types work out as expected, I am just not sure what the semantics of `class Bar extends CoolMixin` are. The way I see it extending the mix-in directly is as if you are just using the mixin class as the base class without it having been applied to anything

```
type Constructor<T = any, A extends any[] = any[]> = new (...a: A) => T

// The function is not generic on two type parameters:
// it is a generic type on TSub as that is fixed during definition
// and a generic function on TSuper as that is defined during the mix-in call
// although TSub does not much matter so we can erase it
type MixinFunction = <TSuper>(base: Constructor<TSuper>) => Constructor<TSuper>

declare function Mixin<T extends MixinFunction>(mixinFn: T): ReturnType<T> & { mixin: T }

// Then using it like so:
// The {} in the extends is critical to allow ReturnType above to get an insatnce of mixin as if applied to {}.
const CoolMixinFunction = <T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base: T) => {
    return class CoolMixin extends Base {
        coolProp = 42
    }
}

const CoolMixin = Mixin(CoolMixinFunction)

const CoolFoo = CoolMixin.mixin(class Foo {
    foo = 'asdf'
})

const c = new CoolFoo()
c.foo
c.coolProp

const CoolBar = class Bar extends CoolMixin {
    bar = 'asdf'
}

const b = new CoolBar()
b.bar
b.coolProp
```

([playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Constructor%3CT%20%3D%20any%2C%20A%20extends%20any%5B%5D%20%3D%20any%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20new%20(...a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20T%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20The%20function%20is%20not%20generic%20on%20two%20type%20parameters%3A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20it%20is%20a%20generic%20type%20on%20TSub%20as%20that%20is%20fixed%20during%20definition%0D%0A%2F%2F%20and%20a%20generic%20function%20on%20TSuper%20as%20that%20is%20defined%20during%20the%20mix-in%20call%0D%0A%2F%2F%20although%20TSub%20does%20not%20much%20matter%20so%20we%20can%20erase%20it%0D%0Atype%20MixinFunction%20%3D%20%3CTSuper%3E(base%3A%20Constructor%3CTSuper%3E)%20%3D%3E%20Constructor%3CTSuper%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20Mixin%3CT%20extends%20MixinFunction%3E(mixinFn%3A%20T)%3A%20ReturnType%3CT%3E%20%26%20%7B%20mixin%3A%20T%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Then%20using%20it%20like%20so%3A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20The%20%7B%7D%20in%20the%20extends%20is%20critical%20to%20allow%20ReturnType%20above%20to%20get%20an%20insatnce%20of%20mixin%20as%20if%20applied%20to%20%7B%7D.%0D%0Aconst%20CoolMixinFunction%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20Constructor%3C%7B%7D%3E%3E(Base%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20class%20CoolMixin%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20coolProp%20%3D%2042%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20CoolMixin%20%3D%20Mixin(CoolMixinFunction)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20CoolFoo%20%3D%20CoolMixin.mixin(class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%20%3D%20'asdf'%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20c%20%3D%20new%20CoolFoo()%0D%0Ac.foo%0D%0Ac.coolProp%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20CoolBar%20%3D%20class%20Bar%20extends%20CoolMixin%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%20%3D%20'asdf'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20new%20CoolBar()%0D%0Ab.bar%0D%0Ab.coolProp%0D%0A))

Comment: "The way I see it extending the mix-in directly is as if you are just using the mixin class as the base class without it having been applied to anything". Yeah, the Mixin tool returns an application of the mixin which if called internally, so it returns the class that the mixin generates, but it calls it with a default base class (Object as the default base class). Then it sticks the `.mixin` property on the generated class before returning it.

Comment: Doesn't the mixin function return `Constructor<TSub & TSuper>`, because it returns the constructor for the generated subclass?

Comment: @trusktr well `TSub` will actually be a subtype of `TSuper` so `TSub & TSuper` can be reduced to `TSub`. The main idea here is that we don't really care what `TSub` is, all we care is that the mixin function returns something that is at least `TSuper`

Comment: Just seems like there's something missing, but in practice I see that it works. Is there a way to make it infer to return the type `constructor<TSub>`?